# Merging of multiple file through one .py file

Tags: python

I have written a function in python which generate 17 output file and my python code  file name is main.py. Now, I want to merge all these 17 txt files into one result.xml file. To do so, I added the code to merge the files in the same main.py. when I ran the code the merger of the 17 files is not working properly and output file does not generated the line in proper sequence However when I break the code into 2 set (one for creation of 17 file and other for merging (the same code used in main.py is broken into two parts) and run it separately the result.xml file is generated properly. Can any one pls explain me why the same code is giving different result when run together ( 1st part of the code and second part of the code) as compare to the running the two part separately?

Comment: you will need to share the code fir debug

Comment: did you put your code in functions? something like `def fuu(): #create *.txt`and then `def bar(): # merge the files`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might want to add some code for some proper help, but in general you code might look like this:

```
files = ["path/to/file1.txt", "path/to/file1.txt", etc ...]
with open("path/to/result.xml", 'w') as result:
    for file in files:
        with open(file) as content:
            result.write(content.read())
```

I don't know why your code fails, as you did not provide any example or error message so far, so i will just guess that you messed up opening multiple files at once. This would be a logical mistake, as this is the main difference between your programs (from your description).